# calculating limit for a sech function

Tags: limits

is any answer in terms of dirac delta function?
how can i calculate this expression?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over \sqrt{x}} \text{sech} \left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply L'Hospital's rule

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over \sqrt{x}} \text{sech} (\frac{1}{x})=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x^{-1/2}}{e^{1/x}+e^{-1/x}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-x^{-3/2}}{(e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x})x^{-2}}\\=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-x^{1/2}}{(e^{1/x}-e^{-1/x})}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over \sqrt{x}} \text{sech} \left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{\cosh (\frac{1}{x})}$

$t=\frac{1}{x}$

$=\lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{\cosh (t)}$

Applying L'Hopital's rule:

$=\lim_{t\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{t}\sinh{t}}$

$=\frac{1}{\infty}$

$=0$

Comment: thank you Mathnoob.does this funnction approches to a delta function?

Comment: It does not seem like it would, as the denominator is undefined ${{x:x<0}}$

Comment: exactly. suppose that in denominator, we have abs(x).

Comment: then yes, i believe. Here's a graph of it http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%7C%282sqrt%28x%29sinh%28x%29%29%7C